# How to Kubernetes pods as Rundeck nodes

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, rundeck

i have a rundeck server running from inside my kubernetes cluster and i need to allow it to see other pods as nodes so i can execute jobs on these pods. Is there a way besides using the official plugin?
I tried using the official plugin Kubernetes Steps and Node Executor but everytime the pod restarts i need to install python and libs to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the best approach is to use an extended docker image which includes Python and the rest of the libraries. Take a look [this](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/tree/master/config) official example, just adding the CMD commands to update and add the python/libraries and changing the ADD command to put the latest k8s plugin on the Dockerfile does the trick.